# The current box background mode 0 is not supported by the end icon mode 3

Tags: android

Android Gradle Plugin Version:

```
4.1.3
```

Gradle Version:

```
7.1.1
```

min SDK version:

```
24
```

Target SDK version:

```
30
```

Dependencies:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
// CameraX core library using the camera2 implementation
def camerax_version = "1.0.1"
// The following line is optional, as the core library is included indirectly by camera-camera2
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}")
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}")
// If you want to additionally use the CameraX Lifecycle library
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}")
// If you want to additionally use the CameraX View class
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha27")
// If you want to additionally use the CameraX Extensions library
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha27")
```

FATAL EXCEPTION:
The current box background mode 0 is not supported by the end icon mode 3

code lines where the problem is:

```
val c = ContextThemeWrapper(this,R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox_ExposedDropdownMenu)
val myTextInputLayout = TextInputLayout(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new style that extends `Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox_ExposedDropdownMenu` and add the following to it:

```
<item name="endIconMode">dropdown_menu</item>
<item name="boxBackgroundMode">outline</item>
```

It will get you much closer to what you want. But my ultimate solution was to create a TextInputLayout XML, inflate it, change whatever I needed, and then add it to the main layout programmatically.